# Diophantine approximation problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Denote $||x||=Min(x-[x],1-(x-[x]))$,it means the minimum distance between x and an integer.

Can we find a fast algorithm to get a natural number $n$ that satisfies
$$||na||<p,||nb||<p,...$$
where $a,b,...$ are given irrational numbers,and $p$ is a positive real number.I know it exists infinite such $n$,but I wonder how to find them in a fast way.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103383/rational-approximation-to-a-set-of-reals) was answered on MathOverflow.

It cited [these notes](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~Doug.Hensley/SimultaneousDiophantine.pdf) which refer to [this algorithm](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-69/3/464.abstract).